# Side-by-side diffs are not side-by-side

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, diff

This only seems to be an issue here on Meta. When in the side-by-side edit view, the two versions appear above each other instead of beside. The issue does not seem to depend on the browser width, and does not occur for side-by-side markdown.

[image: This is the first edited post I saw which wasn't too long]

Comment: -1 for using my edit as an example.

Comment: At least one more site with the same issue is http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `#mainbar-full` div has a different width here than on other Stack Exchange sites. For example, on Stack Overflow, the element has the following styling:

```
#mainbar-full,.mainbar-full {
    width:980px
}
```

However, on Meta SE, the following rules exist:

```
#mainbar-full,.mainbar-full{
    width:980px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:1px
}

#mainbar-full {
    padding:20px;
    width:940px
}
```

So the later rule will override the (default SE style?) 980 pixel width that is also used on other Stack Exchange sites and instead set a width of 940 pixel plus 20 pixel padding on each side. While this will result in the same total outer width for the element (20 + 940 + 20), the content will still have 40 pixel less to spend.

Now, each post excerpt on each side of the actual-side-by-side diff get this style:

```
#revisions .sidebyside-diff>div{
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    width:440px
}
```

So each post will occupy 460 pixels, resulting in a total width of 920, although—at this depth due to margins and paddings of other elements—only 910 pixels are left, being just 10 pixels short to display it next to each other.

So a simple fix that wouldn’t impact the layout too much would be changing the `#mainbar-full` to a width of `950px` and a padding of `15px` instead to make it work again. But of course, the padding can also be further reduced to make it more safe.

(The exact same situation applies to [graphicdesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).)

Answer (score 6):

Jin pushed a fix that will go live in the next build. Keep an eye out for rev 2014.4.24.2188.

Comment: And guess what? This answer helped me find another bug! (dinner time so report will come later, it's the bounty hover state)

Comment: By the way, why not give Jin the honor of posting the answer? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think the bounty thing is already reported: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230370/the-entire-answer-is-moving-when-hovering-the-bounty-button. And because REP GLORIOUS REP (and Jin's busy).

Comment: Yup, that's the bug. Thanks for saving me from posting a dupe!