# The entire answer is moving when hovering the bounty button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

It's just a minor CSS issue. See the following gif:

> [image]

Comment: A bit off-topic, but: could I ask what software you used to make that gif? It really looks quite nice.

Comment: I am on a Linux machine running Ubuntu 14.04. and I used [`byzanz-record`](http://askubuntu.com/a/123515/148451). I created my own `byzanz-record` GUI wrapper, that I shared on my [GitHub account](https://github.com/IonicaBizau). But [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/201018/148451) you will find a shell script that is very easy to use after installing the dependencies.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: Wow. That is AWESOME. I've been looking for something like that for ages. Thank you!

Comment: @AmalMurali You're welcome. :-)

Comment: Start bounties to repro.

Comment: @hims056 Opened on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214531/205508).

Comment: Still an issue…

Comment: LOL @ the petting the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved as part of design overhaul MSE went through not long ago. Now both normal and hovered states have blue square background of the same size, as it should be.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like the problem is that there class `.bounty-vote-off`, which is used to style the un-awarded bounty button when you're *not* hovering the cursor over it, has an extra `padding: 2px 4px 3px` style that doesn't match the `padding: 0.2em 0.5em` style for the `.bounty-award` class.

Simply removing the `padding` style from `.bounty-vote-off` should fix this bug.

Ps. I'm pretty sure this also affects several other SE sites besides MSE, including (at least) the recently graduated Academia.SE and [graphicdesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/bounty-award-hover-state-causes-page-shifting).

---

Actually, the real cause of this bug seems to be that the bounty icon styling on this site (and on Academia / Graphic Design / etc.) is a Frankenstein hybrid of two entirely different styles:

**SOFU style (SO):**

[image: Awarded bounty icon on Stack Overflow]
[image: Unawarded bounty icon on Stack Overflow]

**Beta style (crypto.SE):**

[image: Awarded bounty icon on beta Stack Exchange site]
[image: Unawarded bounty icon on beta Stack Exchange site]

**Frankenstein style (meta.SE):**

[image: Awarded bounty icon on Meta Stack Exchange]
[image: Unawarded bounty icon on Meta Stack Exchange]

Frankly, I suspect that whoever designed these stylesheets simply started from the beta styles and tweaked them to look more like SO, but forgot to modify or test the unawarded bounty appearance.

**Ps.** Looks like the CSS fix included in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script for [this related design issue](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5773) also fixes this bug as a side effect.